# Making the text appear from the bottom of TextField

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm working on a simple chat application in Flash / AS3.  There's a Chat input box, a Send button, and a TextField where the contents of the chat input box appear after the message has been sent.

By default, when you add text to a TextField, the text appears at the top, and works it's way down to the bottom.  I would like to do (something close to) the opposite: Have new messages appear at the bottom of the TextField, and old messages move up to the top as new messages are added.

Is there an easy way to do this with a TextField?  Should I change my TextField to a different component that supports this?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: does your textfield have fixed size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[let me know if this code is needed here, i posted it on wonderfl.net](http://wonderfl.net/c/3cHE)

Comment: Hi.  This looks like exactly what I'm trying to do, but I'm having trouble understanding the code.  Could you explain how everything works in the onclick function? I see that's where you add a line, but I'm having trouble understanding the syntax.  Thanks.

Comment: @rottendevice: i'd better comment my code there or paste that function here? what is more convinient for you?

Comment: Code comments are preferable.  But either way is great, thanks!

Comment: @rottendevice: added comments, same link in my answer

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what you mean. I did something similar a while ago. What I did was use a TextArea to display the text so that I could manipulate the vertical scrollbar. What I did was first check to see whether or not the verticalScrollPosition was equal to maxVerticalScrollPosition. Then add the text to the TextArea. Finally, either set the vertical scroll to the maximum again, if they were equal, or set it to what it was prior to adding the text if they're not equal. This makes it so that if the user scrolls up through the history they won't be brought back down every time a new message comes in.

Comment: Thanks.  This is helpful for getting the TextArea instance to scroll automatically when there's more text than can fit in the TextArea.  But I'm looking for a way to make a new message from the chat appear on the bottom of the TextArea by default.  So, the first message that's added appears at the bottom of the TextArea, not the top.  And the newest messages always appear at the bottom, with the older ones getting pushed up to the top.

Comment: Would that just be (pardon the incorrect syntax) MyTextArea.text += newText?

Comment: No. When you do that, the new text is first added to the top, then gradually down the TextBox.  I'd like the text to be added to the bottom, then gradually up the TextBox.